# Does there exist a continuous function $f$ such that $d_{x}(x_{n},x) \leq f (d_{y}(y_{n},y))$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, metric-spaces, inverse-function

Suppose $(\mathcal{X},d_{x})$ and $(\mathcal{Y},d_{y})$ are metric spaces, and suppose that $\{x_{n}\}$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{X}$ and $\{y_{n}\}$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{Y}$ with $y_{n} = g(x_{n})$, $y = g(x)$ and $g:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ continuous.

My question is:

1. If $d_{y}(y_{n},y)\to 0  $ implies $d_{x}(x_{n},x)\to 0$, is it possible to construct a continuous function $f: \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $d_{x}(x_{n},x) \leq f (d_{y}(y_{n},y))$?
2. If (1) is not possible, what if $g$ is uniformly continuous?

**Further Background:** To me, this question is related the existence of a continuous inverse function $g^{-1}$ that maps "close points" in $\mathcal{Y}$ to "close points" in $\mathcal{X}$. To invoke something like the [inverse function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) seems to require some assumptions on $g$ beyond continuity or uniform continuity (for example, it seems impossible when $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}^{d}$ with $d>1$ and $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}$). But even if a continuous inverse exists, I am not sure that continuity of $g^{-1}$ necessarily means we can construct a continuous $f: \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $d_{x}(x_{n},x) \leq f (d_{y}(y_{n},y))$. My intuition says that none of these statements are true, but I have had trouble proving it/providing a counterexample.

References are especially welcome!

Comment: The \mapsto notation is used to specify what a particular function does to elements. For instance the function $f(x) = x^2$ would be written $f\colon x\mapsto x^2$, but you would write $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ to specify domain and codomain.

Comment: @AOrtiz Thanks for your comment: I always wondering about that and it is good to know!